# Android ListView Subitems

Tags: java, android

I recently created a new ListView object for an Android application, but I am encountering some errors. When I try using a Simple Adapter to create an Item that includes a subitem on my list, The newest item created overlaps the other ones. I am using a List of Maps to create the items.

For example, If I add an item to my map list that displays "1" with a subitem that displays "A1", the item and subitems will be displayed. But if I add an new item to my map list named "2" with a subitem "B2", the "1" and "A1" will be replaced with "2" and "B2". There will still be 2 items on the ListView, but one of them is empty and the other one is "2" and "B2"

Here is my code:

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datum.put("RouterName", "Test1");
        datum.put("RouterIP", "SubTest1");
        data.add(datum);

        Map<String, String> datum2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datum.put("RouterName", "Test2");
        datum.put("RouterIP", "SubTest2");
        data.add(datum2);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"RouterName", "RouterIP"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Changing the list type will not work because the Simple Adapter specifically uses a Map List.

Comment: `datum2` isn't used in this code...??

Comment: @txtechelp, That was bad copying on my part... I somehow messed up on copying the code from my editor.

Comment: make custom adapter of any Value Object(VO) class which contains your two String means TextView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi I found some minor mistakes while storing in Hashmap. In that HashMap object is not creating. Previous instance is getting deleted.

Kindly use the below code. Hope it will help you.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private String[] titleArray,subItemArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    titleArray=new String[]{"Test1","Test2"};
    subItemArray=new String[]{"SubTest1","SubTest2"};
    for(int i=0;i<titleArray.length;i++){
        HashMap<String,String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datum.put("RouterName", titleArray[i]);
        datum.put("RouterIP", subItemArray[i]);
        data.add(datum);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"RouterName", "RouterIP"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```