# Android ListView with subitem causes TwoLineListItem cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I've created a ListView that can display a list of items and subitems, following this question: [android-listview-subitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532652/android-listview-subitems).

However, when I click on one of the rows, I get the error: E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TwoLineListItem cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

The error only started occurring once I added a subitem to each item in the ListView.

The error occurs in the listener for the listView which is this code below:

```
   //listview listener
lvAppFeatures.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //find the selected item and store the value to send to next screen
        strSelectedFeature = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

        //move to display screen
        Intent switchActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                NextActivity.class);

        startActivity(switchActivity);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to have a set of items and a subitems in a ListView but have intent to open another activity work?

Comment: This question has been down voted? Without an explanation? If you've down voted the question, I'd sure like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2

```
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="2dip"
android:paddingBottom="2dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/listItemFirstLineStyle"/>

<TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/listItemSecondLineStyle" />

</TwoLineListItem>
```

A) 
get item directly from adapter

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //find the selected item and store the value to send to next screen
    strSelectedFeature = (String)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

or B), if you want to have access to textviews

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //find the selected item and store the value to send to next screen
    TextView textView1 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView textView2 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    //do other things like textView1.getText() etc
```

Comment: Thanks Aelimill - I accepted the answer and went essentially with the first approach. As a result of your first suggestion I just accessed the incoming parameter "position" directly to get the row selected. Didn't need to use the strSelectedFeature = (String)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position); as this crashed for me.